# Hidden Field As Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, hidden-field

I have an interesting problem, in my form I have this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
      action="@Url.Action("Edit", "Data")">
    @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Metadata.Name)
    <input name="@Html.NameFor(i => i.RecordKey)" type="hidden" value="@Model.RecordKey" />
```

I've tried with both the RecordKey field as @Html.HiddenFor, and with the approach above, and for this one I'm getting a value returned as:

```
string[] { "value" }
```

It's returning a one value array, not just the string directly.  In the model, RecordKey is typed as Object, as it may be an integer in some scenarios, and others a string.  Any idea why this is posted back this way?  I thought maybe I had dual inputs with this name, but it's not anywhere else in the model...

I had a model defined as:

```
public class FormModel
{
   public object RecordKey { get; set; }
}
```

And the action that receives it is the following.  Once I get the data back, FormModel has a single array and I used the following to convert it.

```
public ActionResult Edit(FormModel model)
{
   if (model.RecordKey is string[])
      model.RecordKey = ((string[])model.RecordKey).First();
}
```

On the client, it's what you would expect:

```
<input name="RecordKey" type="hidden" value="X"></input>
```

I'm not quite sure why it's doing that in the first place...  No custom model binding is in place...

Comment: How are you getting this "value returned"? How do you bind and read it?

Comment: Show your controller action and custom model-binders (if any).

Comment: Added.  No custom model binding in place.

Comment: What value do you pass to the view? What does the hidden input's value look like in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't showing because I formatted it wrong, but it appears as above. Value is X, which is sent and does come back correctly, but is in an array.  Name matches correctly...

Comment: Because your property is typeof `object`. Change it to `public string RecordKey { get; set; }` and `@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.RecordKey)`

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you have declared you property as typeof `object`. The default model binder has no way of knowing if your posting back a value type (`string`, `int` etc.) or a collection of values so when it first initializes your model it creates an array to allow for all possibilities (and adds the posted values to that array). If you change your property to

```
public string RecordKey { get; set; }
```

Then it will be correctly bound as a `string`